# C# How to delete every character after something on every line

Tags: c#, .net

So I've been trying to figure out how to delete characters after a certain point on each line, for example I have a list like:

```
dskfokes=dasfn3rewk
dsanfiwen=434efsde
damkw4343=o3rm3i
dmfkim303rk2=0439wefksd
32i32j9esfj=42393jdsf
```

How would I go about deleting everything on each line after `'='`?

Comment: how about using regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a combination of string handling operations `SubString` and `IndexOf` to achieve this, consider the example:

```
List<string> inputLine = new List<string>(){ "dskfokes=dasfn3rewk",
                                          "dsanfiwen=434efsde",
                                          "damkw4343=o3rm3i",
                                          "dmfkim303rk2=0439wefksd",
                                          "32i32j9esfj=42393jdsf"};
List<string> outputLines = inputLine.Select(x => 
                           x.IndexOf('=') == -1 ? x :
                           x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('='))).ToList();
```

**Note :** The `IndexOf` will return `-1` if the specified index was not found, in such cases `substring` method will throws errors since `-1` will not be a valid index. So we have to check for existence of index withing the string before proceeding. you can also try simple `foreach` as like this:

```
List<string> outputLines=new List<string>();
int currentCharIndex=-1;
foreach (string line in inputLine)
{
    currentCharIndex = line.IndexOf('=');
    if(currentCharIndex ==-1)
        outputLines.Add(line);
    else
        outputLines.Add(line.Substring(0,currentCharIndex));
}
```

Comment: duplicate `IndexOf ` calls. Yuck.

Answer (score 4):

Use string.IndexOf() to get the index of the char you want to remove, then string.Remove() to do the removing.

```
string str = "dskfokes=dasfn3rewk";
str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf('='));
```

Comment: +1, but I'd add that before passing the result to `Remove()` it would be best to check that an index was actually found.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use LINQ:

```
var strings = new string[] {
    "dskfokes=dasfn3rewk
,   "dsanfiwen=434efsde
,   "damkw4343=o3rm3i
,   "dmfkim303rk2=0439wefksd
,   "32i32j9esfj=42393jdsf
};
var res = strings.Select(s => s.Split('=')[0]).ToArray();
```

This splits each string on `=`, and drops everything after the first `'='` character if it is there.

Comment: Using `Split()` is overkill when you just need the portion up to the first `=` sign.

Comment: @SamuelNeff It is a small overkill for a situation when there's only a few equal signs in the string. On the other hand, it lets you skip `-1` check when `=` is not there.

Comment: It's not just overkill if there are more than one equal signs. With `IndexOf` the search will stop once the first is found, whereas with `Split` it will continue regardless. Additionally `Split` will allocate an array of strings whereas `IndexOf` with `Substring` will only allocate another string. Of course I concede that the level of overkill is minor and would never be a bottleneck in any real world situation, I just personally like to avoid unnecessary overkill. You are right about `Split` obviating the need for the index check though. It's really a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it using `String.Split()` like

```
string[] allWords = new string[] {
"dskfokes=dasfn3rewk",
"dsanfiwen=434efsde",
"damkw4343=o3rm3i",
"dmfkim303rk2=0439wefksd",
"32i32j9esfj=42393jdsf"
};

foreach(string s in allWords)
{
    string[] urstring = s.Split('=');
    Console.WriteLine(urstring[0]);
}
```